# Backstage - Why are the resource types and default being appended on the names on our deployed version

Tags: yaml, backstage

Good day
We have deployed [Backstage](https://backstage.io/) within our workplace AWS environments and have run into a strange bug between local and our deployed/staging env

We use Backstage to scaffold systems and services to reflect in Argo-CD, just for background. What Backstage allows us is to create the templates we will use for these purposes

We have now run into said bug that we cannot produce on local.
Once a user has finished entering their details for a system creation for example, the final option is to verify/confirm the details entered. Here we can see the values about to be used in the background tasks and such

On local, all is fine on this screen. The values are correct and can be used going forward. Please ignore screen layouts, some work is yet to be published, logic is the same however

[image: local working]

On the deployed side, the values are appended with what we assume is Backstage's resource type and :

[image: live staging not working as intended]

To be clear what is happening here. The first fields are text fields the user will input for their naming conventions. The groups are chosen from drop down lists. Anything with resource*:default is selected from previously loaded lists. Yet on local we do not have this appending information/text
This will not help us as we use the values here to create the Argo-CD data and some more Gitlab work (creating repositories, groups)
It will not work with the names suddenly being

> group:default/g_odin_devx_admin

or

> resource:default/our-system

To replicate this, we have tried the following:

- Deleting local databases for our Windows users. These get recreated when the application is set to run again
- Switching to point to the deployed database
- Deleting the deployed database and recreating it
- Comparing all files, configs and settings. Nothing is different

None of these have worked. Again, it is a difference between local and deployed.
Our YAML files are the same, just added new fields for local for new work, but logic in the tasks is the same

We are now stuck on how to resolve this issue, as Backstage documentation does not have anything on this, nor do the FAQs or community
We are hoping there is someone here who can assist?